# How does Ruby's array work?

Tags: arrays, ruby

When I input

```
p [[2,1],3,4][1][1]
```

It will output 1.

Why is that happening?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `[2,1]` creates an array with two elements (`2`, `1`)
- `[[2,1],3,4]` creates an array with three elements (`[2,1]`, `3` and `4`)
- `[1]` indexes that array and returns the second element `3` (indexing is 0 based)
- `[1]` indexes the second bit of the number `3` (represented in binary as `11`) - aka `1`